# Java Spring shedlock fails

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, shedlock

i have a spring-boot app, which on production environment runs in 2 instances, resulting in scheduled tasks running twice.  to avoid that i'm trying use shedlock, as explained [here](https://www.baeldung.com/shedlock-spring) and [here](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock), but it has no affect.
i'm already using a MySql db, to which i added a `shedlock` table as explained on both of the examples above.

my project's structure is as follows (partially) -

[image]

in my `application.properties` file i have this settings -

```
db.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/b4ad?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
db.username=*****
db.password=*****
```

to the `AppConfig` class i added this annotation -

```
@EnableSchedulerLock(defaultLockAtMostFor = "PT30S")
```

and this bean -

```
@Bean
public LockProvider lockProvider(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplateLockProvider(dataSource, "b4ad.shedlock");
}
```

and in the `ScheduledManager` class i have this scheduled task -

```
 @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * * * ?")
@SchedulerLock(name = "deactivateExpiredOrganizations", lockAtLeastFor = "PT5M")
public void deactivateExpiredOrganizations() {
    // my code...
}
```

when i run my application locally on 2 instances (using 2 different ports in the `application.properties` file), looking at the log i can see that the task runs on both instances, and at the same time the `shedlock` table remains empty.
according to the second item in the [troubleshooting](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock#troubleshooting) section, it seems that i miss-configured something, but i can't tell what.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well create a table ScheduledTask and create a column of type Bit with a name started. Check its value at the beginning of your task. Set it to 1 when the task begins to execute. And if it's already 1 don't start your task. Set it again to 0 after your task completes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, apparently in my big project there was another config class (besides the `AppConfig`) - one called `SqlSpringConfig`, inside the db module.
once i put the `LockProvider` bean there, all works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You should check your taskConfiguration implementation.

I have same issue in my project. Problem is below code.

```
@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {
    private final int POOL_SIZE = 10;

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar) {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();

        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(POOL_SIZE);
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("my-scheduled-task-pool-");
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize();

        scheduledTaskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(threadPoolTaskScheduler);
    }
}
```

We add custom configuration by implementing ScheduledTaskRegistrar for using multi-threading to execute tasks. But if you override configureTasks, shedlock doesn't work. You should inject by using @Bean. So,

```java
    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(POOL_SIZE);
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("custom-scheduler-");
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize();
    
        return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
    }
```

when i change override to inject by @Bean, it works well!

- official github : https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock#taskscheduler-proxy
- why shedlock doesn't work : https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock/issues/137#issuecomment-481596720